# jQuery: How do I prevent select list from resetting itself?

Tags: jquery

I have a code that adds a select list on the front of an 'li' list (which contains another set of select lists), whenever an "Add" button is triggered.

I'll have this...

```
<li><select name="selectbox1><!--OptionsList--></select><select name="selectbox2">
<!--OptionsList--></select></li>
```

And eventually I hope to achieve this after the "Add" button is triggered:

```
<li><select name="newselectbox"></select><select name="selectbox1><!--OptionsList--></select><select name="selectbox2">
<!--OptionsList--></select></li>
```

I've tried using this method where I ammend the 'li' content.

```
$("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html("<select name='cao1' class='cao ops'></select>" +    
$("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html());
```

I find that it works, but if there is a selection in the Select boxes already made, the selection will be 'wiped' clean. I guess it's because I used the **.html()** method, which only grabs the codes rather than the current state of the select boxes. How do I prevent the select list from resetting itself?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kosherjellyfish/2NKUb/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GrzNu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html("<select name='cao1' class='cao ops'></select>" + $("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html());
```

to:

```
$("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").prepend("<select name='cao1' class='cao ops'></select>");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2NKUb/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Before appending the new `select` tag, store the `value` of the **`selectlist1`** in a variable like

```
var d = $("ul.criteriallist li").find('select').val();
```

Then once you set the html, set the value back to it

```
$("ul.criteriallist li").find('select').val(d);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2NKUb/14/)